# Jquery Validation: How to make fields red

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am using jquery and jquery.validate.cs (jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.0) to validate a form.  Right now it displays a message next to a field saying : "This is a required field".

I also want each field to turn red color. How would i do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Without any custom configuration, you can just do this:

```
select.error, textarea.error, input.error {
    color:#FF0000;
}
```

- The default class that is applied to an invalid input is `error`
- The default class for an input that was validated is `valid`.

These classes are also applied to the error label, so be aware of that when writing your CSS.

- Demo with default classes: http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/j3ddP/2/

The [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) allows you to configure these class names, so you may do something like this:

```
$("form").validate({
   errorClass: "my-error-class",
   validClass: "my-valid-class"
});

.my-error-class {
    color:#FF0000;  /* red */
}
.my-valid-class {
    color:#00CC00; /* green */
}
```

- Demo with custom classes: http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/j3ddP/1/

The configuration options can be found at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

Comment: dont use color name; it has been deprecated by w3c; instead use `#F00`

Comment: @diEcho: It's just a demo, but still I have never heard of that. Link please? It may not be recommended, but I doubt very highly it will be deprecated any time soon.

Comment: @Wesley; even in demo you should prefer the best practice bcoz here newbie just follow you :) btw here is the link you want too see :
http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CSS-TECHS/#style-color-contrast

Comment: thank you, setting the css error class works great, but now a related question ... how do i make all of the fields turn back to white as they have been filled in and the user focuses out of them ... right now the select boxes turn white after selection is made but the input boxes don't

Comment: @sam: The inputs won't lose the error class until they become valid, you can see this for yourself in the demo, although I also added a `valid` class (try removing it and running the fiddle again). Can you put up either a jsfiddle or a live demo that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: basically when form is submitted it turns red. then if user enters information and clicks out of field into next field, i want the previous field to turn from red to white since its valid now ... how would i do that?     right now i temporarily made it turn to white onclick - not exactly what i want ... thx

Comment: I'm not sure why it's acting that way on your site. Definitely remove the onclick attributes if you want to figure it out, and try a default validator setup like `$('form').validate()` and see what happens. As you can see from the demo, that isn't normal behavior.

Comment: label.error {
    color:#FF0000;
} worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
$("#myform").validate({
   error: function(label) {
     $(this).addClass("error");
   },
});
```

use the errorClass parameter to add the .invalid class:

```
input.error {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use Firebug to see what the class of the error element is and then use css to make it red:

```
.error-label {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think s/he wants to make the input *field* red, not the *label*.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this code in official docs.
In this example we hightlight both wrong input and its label.

```
$("#myform").validate({
   highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
    .addClass(errorClass);
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
    .removeClass(errorClass);
  }
});
```

You can easily modify it for your needs.
See full documentation here: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight

Answer (score 0):

Just make a style in your css.
when validate() function detects the errors, actually a **"label"** is created to display the error with class name **"error"** so just give the style to this class in your style sheet, like:

label.error{color:#f00;}

or
.error{color:#f00;}

Thats It..

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight your input field border using the below CSS.

```
input.error, textarea.error, select.error  {
    border-color:#f00;
}
```